Tengo error en la parte "Dimension arreglo[n] Como Entero"
Corregir la parte de "Dimension arreglo[n] Como Entero"
Algoritmo caso1
Definir n, i Como Entero
Definir datos Como Entero
Escribir "¿Cuántos datos desea ingresar?"
Leer n

Dimension arreglo[n] Como Entero 

Para i <- 1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir "Ingrese el dato ", i, ":"
    Leer arreglo[i]
FinPara

Escribir "Los datos ingresados son:"

Para i <- 1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Escribir arreglo[i]
FinPara

FinAlgoritmo

Hola, no entiendo muy bien, cuál es especificamente el error que presentas en tú codigo? De momento, te invido a que leas cómo realizar una pregunta [ask]  y también que realices el [tour] Saludos.
